# Write a borland database engine with php

Tags: php, dbase

I need to write a borland database engine (dbase) from php.
I know it's not recommanded, and probably a bad idea, but I have to link my data to a software that only read dbase file.

So anyone know how to create from scratch a borland db from php?

Comment: Easy, `$db = new BorlandDb()`. But really.. can you be more specific?

Comment: Yes, I do know how to do that. Now do you have an additional (more detailed) question, or were you just checking whether there's anyone else who can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean dbase like [DBF files dbase](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dbase.php)?

Comment: eh?? That shows how to access a dbf database. Not how to write your own db engine from scratch in php. How did this answer your question @Etienne? It's the difference between asking *"How can I write MySQL"* vs *"How can I access MySQL with PHP"*

Comment: It answer it, because insted of calling new BorlandB, a class that dosen't exist, he gave me the real class that do exist

Comment: @MikeB Sometimes the real problem is communication, not technical.